# Get CPU and RAM usage

Tags: c#, cpu-usage, system.diagnostics

I need to get the ram memory and CPU usage during execution of a process (the process can run sometimes and over 30 minutes). I am able to get the free RAM but the CPU usage it's not correct, compared with the value from task manager. Am I doing something wrong? Here is my code:

```
class Program
{
    static List<float> AvailableCPU = new List<float>();
    static List<float> AvailableRAM = new List<float>();

    protected static PerformanceCounter cpuCounter;
    protected static PerformanceCounter ramCounter;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        cpuCounter = new PerformanceCounter();
        cpuCounter.CategoryName = "Processor";
        cpuCounter.CounterName = "% Processor Time";
        cpuCounter.InstanceName = "_Total";

        ramCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Memory", "Available MBytes");

        try
        {
            System.Timers.Timer t = new System.Timers.Timer(1200);
            t.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(TimerElapsed);
            t.Start();
            Thread.Sleep(10000);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("catched exception");
        }
        Console.ReadLine();

    }

    public static void TimerElapsed(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        float cpu = cpuCounter.NextValue();
        float ram = ramCounter.NextValue();
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("CPU Value: {0}, ram value: {1}", cpu, ram));
        AvailableCPU.Add(cpu);
        AvailableRAM.Add(ram);
    }

}
```

But when I run the program, here is what it's printed to the console, compared with values from task manager:
[image: cpu usage]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It is fluctuating on the display - perhaps you're comparing different time ranges?  You _do_ have a 2.7 value in there...

Comment: I've added a method to simulate cpu load and the values are not even close with the ones from the task manager. I read the values once a second.  I suspect that this may be due to the multi core cpu, but I'm not sure yet...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your values.

The reason you see differences with what task manager returns is that the "CPU usage" value is something computed *for a given interval*, i.e. between two `NextValue()` calls. If task manager "doesn't call its own NextValue" (if we simplify how it works) at the same time you do, you won't return the same results.

Imagine the following scenario:

```
Time 0: 0% actual CPU usage
Time 1: 50% actual CPU usage
Time 2: 70% actual CPU usage
Time 3: 2% actual CPU usage
Time 4: 100% actual CPU usage
```

- If you check the value between Time 1 and Time 3, you'll return something based on "50% and 2%".
- If task manager checks the value between Time 2 and Time 4, it'll return something different, i.e. a value based on "70% and 100%".

You could try to spawn multiple processes of your own application, you should also see different results.

Answer (score 8):

Here is what I've found: I've created a list with `PerformanceCounter` objects for each core, I add the percent and divide the result at number of phisical cores:

```
    class Program
    {
        static List<float> AvailableCPU = new List<float>();
        static List<float> AvailableRAM = new List<float>();

        protected static PerformanceCounter cpuCounter;
        protected static PerformanceCounter ramCounter;
        static List<PerformanceCounter> cpuCounters = new List<PerformanceCounter>();
        static int cores = 0;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            cpuCounter = new PerformanceCounter();
            cpuCounter.CategoryName = "Processor";
            cpuCounter.CounterName = "% Processor Time";
            cpuCounter.InstanceName = "_Total";

            foreach (var item in new System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher("Select * from Win32_Processor").Get())
            {
                cores = cores + int.Parse(item["NumberOfCores"].ToString());
            }

            ramCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Memory", "Available MBytes");

            int procCount = System.Environment.ProcessorCount;
            for(int i = 0; i < procCount; i++)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter pc = new System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter("Processor", "% Processor Time", i.ToString());
                cpuCounters.Add(pc);
            }

            Thread c = new Thread(ConsumeCPU);
            c.IsBackground = true;
            c.Start();

            try
            {
                System.Timers.Timer t = new System.Timers.Timer(1200);
                t.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(TimerElapsed);
                t.Start();
                Thread.Sleep(10000);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("catched exception");
            }
            Console.ReadLine();

        }

        public static void ConsumeCPU()
        {
            int percentage = 60;
            if (percentage < 0 || percentage > 100)
                throw new ArgumentException("percentage");
            Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
            watch.Start();
            while (true)
            {
                // Make the loop go on for "percentage" milliseconds then sleep the 
                // remaining percentage milliseconds. So 40% utilization means work 40ms and sleep 60ms
                if (watch.ElapsedMilliseconds > percentage)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(100 - percentage);
                    watch.Reset();
                    watch.Start();
                }
            }
        }

        public static void TimerElapsed(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            float cpu = cpuCounter.NextValue();
            float sum = 0;
            foreach(PerformanceCounter c in cpuCounters)
            {
                sum = sum + c.NextValue();
            }
            sum = sum / (cores);
            float ram = ramCounter.NextValue();
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("CPU Value 1: {0}, cpu value 2: {1} ,ram value: {2}", sum, cpu, ram));
            AvailableCPU.Add(sum);
            AvailableRAM.Add(ram);
        }

    }
```

Here is the screenshot with the results (as you can see, the first method is more precise):

[image]

Comment: Wow, that's exactly what I was looking for. But I don't understand why the timer is set to 1200? Cause if I try to change the number, I start to get different results