# Continously monitoring thread for CPU usage

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer, windows-services

I need a thread in Windows Service which keep monitoring the CPU usage (maybe every 5 seconds). If the CPU usage is low then other thread should be activated.

I have found a sample CPU usage monitoring code from this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33387425/get-cpu-and-ram-usage) (given below in my post too). This the code for Console application and to keep the `Timer` alive, the person is using `Console.ReadLine();`   at the end.

**CPU usage Console Application:**

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Timers;
using System.Threading;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace CPUPerformanceMonitor
{
    class MonitoringApplication
    {
        protected static PerformanceCounter cpuCounter;
        protected static PerformanceCounter ramCounter;

        public static void TimerElapsed(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            float cpu = cpuCounter.NextValue();
            float ram = ramCounter.NextValue();
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("CPU Value: {0}, ram value: {1}", cpu, ram));
        }

        public static void Main()
        {
            cpuCounter = new PerformanceCounter();
            cpuCounter.CategoryName = "Processor";
            cpuCounter.CounterName = "% Processor Time";
            cpuCounter.InstanceName = "_Total";

            ramCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Memory", "Available MBytes");

            try
            {
                System.Timers.Timer t = new System.Timers.Timer(1200);
                t.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(TimerElapsed);
                t.Start();
                Thread.Sleep(10000);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("catched exception");
            }

            while (true) //Another sample BAD way to keep the timer alive
            { }

            //Console.ReadLine(); //just to keep the time alive
        }
    }
}
```

**PROBLEM:** How do I implement it in Windows-Service application. I mean, how do I keep the thread alive.

**My Windows-Service Structure:**

I call a Thread callback method `OnStart()`. This thread-Callback method calls the `StartCPUMonitorinig()` method of class `CPUMonitor` (which contains the code for `Timer`).

```
    public void CPUMonitorinigThreadCallback()
    {
        //If nothing is there in this function, the thread will start up and then immediately shutdown. To deal with this situation, use "_shutdownEvent"
        //The while loop checks the ManualResetEvent to see if it is "set" or not.
        while (!_shutdownEvent.WaitOne(0))
        {
            // Replace the Sleep() call with the work you need to do
            //Sleep(1000);
            objCPUMonitor.StartCPUMonitorinig();
        }

    }
```

Comment: I think you are approaching this the wrong way. It sounds like you are basically trying to get some work done, but only when the CPU utilization is low. Have you considered that you could simply lower the priority of your worker thread (background, idle, etc.)? If I've misunderstood your intentions, could you give me the broader picture of what you are trying to achieve (in general)?

Comment: why do you need a thread. You can use a timer to fire every 5 seconds.

Comment: The Windows Service thread does not go to sleep. You basically don't need to do anything it will be kept alive, so long as you register for events, they will be raised\

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer: you are right. I have a thread which continously monitor if an USB stick has been inserted. I need to copy the files from USB if and only if the CPU usage is low. BROAD PICTURE: Start monitoring the CPU usage as soon as the USB is inserted and copy files when CPU usage is low.

Comment: Then Manfred is right - just lower the priority of the worker thread.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why the CPU usage has to be low? File I/O is usually not fast enough to impact CPU utilization that much (and if it was, the program would interfere with itself and therefore stutter).

Comment: There is an another application which need too much CPU resources (nearly 90 percent CPU usage) and its performance is highly sensitive in terms of available CPU resources. Therefore, nothing else should be working when this application is running. The file transfer should start only when this top priority application in not running and the CPU resources are available.

Comment: In that case I stand by my original proposition: Lower the thread priority. Keep in mind however, that depending on **how** you copy those files all that monitoring might not have any effect as soon as you start it. Another (and probably better) solution would be to buy a better computer. If copying data from a thumb drive impacts your CPU utilization in a way that some critical process doesn't get enough power ... well it just seems like you are fixing the wrong problems to be honest.

Answer (score 0):

To implement this into a `Service` type you have to consider where and how do you want to output your performance data. Using Windows Service I can recommend making another application or overlay which will then display these values whenever Service ends its update. This can be done using shared memory, file, database, windows message pump, std out etc.

Considering these things you can actually start making your service by making a Service object :

```
public class MeService : ServiceBase
{
    // for the ability to redirect stream
    [DllImport("Kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true) ]
    public static extern int SetStdHandle(int device, IntPtr handle); 

    // entry point
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
        ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[]
        {
            new MeService()
        };
        ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
    }

    PerformanceObject pObject; // object to retrieve and return performance status
    IContainer components;
    FileStream fStream;
    public MeService()
        : base()
    {
        components = new Container(); // initialize components holder
        ServiceName = "MeService"; // set your service name
    }

    // Here check for custom commands on your service
    protected override void OnCustomCommand(int command)
    {
        if(command == 1)
        {
            // redirect stream
            fStream = new FileStream("<path_to_your_out_file>", <FileMode.Here>, <FileAccess.Here>);
            IntPtr streamHandle = fStream.Handle;
            SetStdHandle(-11, handle); // DWORD -11  == STD OUT
        }
        else if(command == 1337 && pObject != null) // example command
        {
            // write string.Format("CPU Value: {0}, ram value: {1}", cpu, ram);
            // into your service's std out
            Console.WriteLine(pObject.GetPerformance()); 
        }
        base.OnCustomCommand(command);
    }

    // whenever service starts create a fresh performance counter object
    protected override void OnStart(string[] args) // will be called when service starts
    {
        pObject = new PerformanceObject();
    }

    // called whenever service is stopped
    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        // remove performance counter object 
        pObject.Dispose();
        pObject = null;
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            if (components != null)
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }

            if (pObject != null)
            {
                pObject.Dispose();
            }
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

Now after you've done with that you can create your "display" application. This should redirect service's std out to it's own reader to make you able to read from that stream.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        FileStream fileStream = new FileStream("<PATH_TO_THE_SAME_FILE_AS_SERVICE>", <FileMode.Here>, <FileAccess.Here>);
        // create service controller that will control "MeService" service
        ServiceController Controller = new ServiceController("MeService");
        if (Controller.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped)
        {
            Controller.Start();
        }

        while (Controller.Status != ServiceControllerStatus.Running)
        ;

        Controller.ExecuteCommand(1); // redirect the stream.           

        string command = string.Empty;
        while( ( command = Console.ReadLine() ) != "exit" )
        {
            if(command == "refresh")
            {
                if (Controller.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Running)
                {
                    Controller.ExecuteCommand(1337);
                    string performance = fileStream.ReadLine();
                    Console.WriteLine(performance);
                } 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now all you have to do is to create an install file in your Service and create `PerformanceObject` which you already have but seams that you will have to modify it a bit to use with above snippets.